# How to enable global "text replacement" globally in OS X Captain?

Tags: macos

Upon specifying the setting as shown in this screenshot:
[Link-to-Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvixe.png), I was able to get automatic text-replacement when I am using the Apple applications, like "Safari", "Notes" and so on; however, the text-replacement does not work in any other non-Apple applications.

Is there a way to specify such text-replacement globally? The crucial ones are the Terminal, Firefox, and Vim.

Search results obtained by quick Googling does not look promising, either as they were years old (more than 3), or relies on external application.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It relies entirely on the Application coders to specifically use the Mac toolbox when they code the app.

Many cross-platform developments cut corners to keep the workload down, meaning they ignore the potential of the Mac's specific text-handling methods & instead employ methods that will work on Mac & Windows without needing extra work.

You could write to them & complain ;)